# Why is Firefox searching with Bing when it shouldn't be?

Tags: firefox, search-engines

I have changed the Firefox default `keyword.url` in `about:config` to `http://www.google.com/search?btnG=Google+Search&q=` but when I search from the address bar it goes to Bing.

How is this possible? I don't even have any occurence of Bing in the `about:config`.

Comment: What is `browser.search.defaultenginename` set to?

Comment: Do you have any add ons installed which could be the culprit?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/156927/how-to-disable-microsoft-hostname-lookup-enhancements

Comment: @ChrisF: Google

Answer (score 0):

change the address in the keyword.url to this instead and try.

`http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=`

hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have tried that, but it didn't work.