# Can someone please explain these Network Activity entries are? (resource monitor windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

The first one is the address microsoftword.com.br. What is this? I noticed when I connected windows to the internet briefly, and it went away soon after.

[image]

when I typed the address into my tablet, it redirected to bing with the search "microsoftword com" with MSSRPD at the end of the address.

The other unknowns seemed to appear when my brothers laptop was connected to the network. Is that normal? Usually if I disconnected and reconnected they would appear, but I noticed when I had disconnected and reconnected to try it didn't happen as he wasn't connected.

[image]

I'm concerned about the microsoftword one is. Is it legitimate? The svchost that associated with is a legit svchost image.

Comment: Why are you worried.  If you have word installed I would expect data to that address we can't tell you about the unknown connection unless you can tell us more

Comment: I dont have word installed. But is it a legitimate domain from Microsoft? Ive used a website to get the domains ip, and it seems to be an ip belonged to Microsoft in redmond

Comment: Its owned by Microsoft based on the name server "msft.net" ownership.  I again wonder the reason your asking there has to be a reason

Comment: So its a legimate domain? I disconnected qnd reconnected this time microsoftauto.com.br came up for roughly 10 seconds (same as last one) is there any reason its appearing?

Comment: I already answered if it was owned by Microsoft....

Comment: So can I ignore it?  It seems it comes up any time I disconnect and reconnect. There was microsoftword, auto and eai. These all seem to be Microsoft products but I dont have any of them.

Comment: You don't have any office product at all?

Comment: I dont believe so. I have wordpad but I doubt thats an office product. Would windows live essentials have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Word and Azure cloud services, this [post](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/11/windows-azures-use-of-non-us-ipv4-address-space-in-us-regions/) might provide some explanation.

Comment: I dont have word and haven't really heard of azure. Other addresses that appeared were microsoftauto.com.br, and microsofteai.com.br. is it possible some windows update caused this?. I read the article but im not sure if its related to what im seeing.

Answer (score 0):

MSSRPD may be Bing toolbar activity.

You can find more informations here:

[Microsoft hides mystery Firefox extension in toolbar update](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/06/microsoft-slips-ie-firefox-add-on-into-toolbar-update/)

and here

[How to disable Microsoft hostname lookup "enhancements"?](https://superuser.com/questions/156927/how-to-disable-microsoft-hostname-lookup-enhancements)

and on many other pages if you search for MSSRPD.

Comment: The mssrpd came from when I entered the address into my tablet. It redirected to bing, with a search result "Microsoftword com"

Comment: So... mystery solved?

Comment: Well I dont know why svchost seems to have a couple bytes outbound towards these Microsoft sites, for products I dont have. It only happens for about 10 seconds after connecting to the Internet. Would could cause svchost to do this?

Comment: Maybe it checks for updates or something like that...

Comment: But i dont have any of the said products. As long as I can be sure this isnt malicious im not bothered, but im not sure.

Comment: microsoftword com is just a domain, bing may use it for spelling check or to work in general. Im not sure about this, just guessing.

Comment: But I dont even use bing. I Dont use IE either. One thing I have not checked is what service is doing this. Is there a way to find out what service is doing this?

Comment: Are you using firefox?

Comment: Googe chrome. I only see this activity for abput 10 seconds after connecting to tye internet, having no contact with any browsers. Different microsoftxxxx.com.br addresses on each connect. I havent rebooted or anything so im not sure of its a temporary thing after an update.